# How to connect the PHPMYADMIN DB to create DB

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to create the batch file which will create the table in Jommla Database, Phpmy admin,
I am trying to connect DB with mysql -uroot -ptest conf
but it is not connecting to the database.

regards
NewDev

Answer (score 0):

If the MySQL server is on your local box, then the command (note the spacing) is this:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

It will prompt you for your root password after you enter that command. If you're connecting to a remote server (and you generally shouldn't allow remote connections as root) you'd use something like this, substituting your server's IP after `-h`:

```
mysql -h 123.456.789.101 -u root -p
```

Once you've logged in, you'll be able to run `CREATE DATABASE` as needed.